# ver datos del archivo a subir en input

Tags: php, html, ajax

Me gustaría saber si es posible que yo al momento de subir un archivo en un input ( html ) en otro campo o ahí mismo mostrar ciertos datos del archivo.

por ejemplo que pinche el input, seleccione el archivo y capturar los datos que necesito, solo para visualizarlos no necesito hacer nada con ellos.

espero me haya explicado, no agrego código ya que no tengo nada de avance vine en busca de ayuda.

Comment: usas un input type="file" ? subes Imágenes o que archivos específicamente?

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Jquery puedes usar un evento que detecte el campo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Fire Event on File Select</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
            alert("un archivo fue seleccionado.");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="file">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```